# Multiple applications on the same URL/Port (IIS)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm developing an ASP.Net MVC application in C#, and it is hosted in an IIS server. Right now the client asked me to have a CMS on the same app url, that will be used to serve the public pages.

I have looked for ASP.Net MVC CMS apps and could not find anything that would be easily integrated with the current application, so I choose to do it by changing the server configuration.

What I need is:

Custom App:

- exampleappurl.com/User
- exampleappurl.com/Company
- etc

CMS:

- Any other URL, including "index" (exampleappurl.com)

Can I do it using any kind of Rewrite rule? Or IIS configuration? What is the best solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IIS6, there is a feature called 'host headers', that does exactly this: several websites may share the port 80, and the request goes to one of the sites its URL points to.

http://www.it-notebook.org/iis/article/understanding_host_headers.htm

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx (this one is about IIS 7)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I may have missed something, but when I followed the instructions on the second link (for IIS7), I could only set one app for using the port 80. When I try to setup the other one, it gives me an error, saying that I can only start one website using that port. May I have missed something?

Comment: I didn't set up IIS7 myself, but I think there's an 'advanced' button, and you can click that and set up multiple listeners on port 80 this way.